# Is it thread-safe to read a property from an instantiated object?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, singleton

Can I safely read a `IsBusy` boolean property for an instantiated singleton from multiple threads without causing any thread-safety issues, or am I already in dangerous waters?

Comment: Depends on how it's implemented.

Comment: Can you give an example of an implementation where it is not safe vs. safe?

Comment: @Vlad: That depends on what you mean by "thread-safe". For example, if the valid can be changed by another thread, is implemented with a simple field with no memory barriers, and you *must* see the change in another thread, then that's not safe.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have for this?

Comment: Depends on what you mean with safe.

Comment: I agree with Jon - is another thread changing this at the same time? What does "thread safe" even mean?

Comment: If you only ever read then there's no problem.  Trouble starts when you also write it.  And of course a property named "IsBusy" is going to written sooner or later.

Comment: ...don't think I deserved the downvote, but oh well.  The answer was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs You had 4 different people asking you for clarifying questions because your question, as it stands, is greatly lacking in information and is not really answerable.  The people who tried to answer had to make up their own examples and try to guess at what you were asking because you didn't provide enough information in your question.  You also clearly have done little to no research into this question before asking it.  All in all I see no reason to upvote this question, as it doesn't demonstrate research, it's not clear, it's not answerable, and as is it's not useful.

Comment: @Servy, obviously I disagree.  Jon Skeet was able to figure out exactly what I was asking, and as usual completely answered it.  If you have a suggestion as to how to improve the question, I'd be interested in hearing it, but it's asking exactly what I wanted to know, and now I know the answer.  I was not sure if using such a property in my singleton would be a good idea; now I know that it isn't.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Jon *guessed* at what you were doing.  He said you *might* be having problems.  He doesn't know.  He *can't* know, and that's because the question doesn't have enough information to be answered.  He had to invent his own question just so that he could answer it, because your question wasn't answerable.  If you want to know what your question is missing, start with all of the existing comments asking you for further information (including Jon by the way).  That will at least give you somewhere to start.

Comment: @Servy I asked if it was thread-safe; the answer is _no_.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs No, the answer is *not* no.  The response is "maybe, we don't know, please provide more information."  Even Jon couldn't say "no", he could only say, "maybe, but here's some other case where the answer *is* no."

Comment: @Servy, there's no point in a continued dialogue on this.  Suffice it to say, I'm happy with the answer, and my question was worded the way it was worded specifically to get the answer I was looking for.  I'm happy with it, downvote notwithstanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you have any memory barriers, you're *potentially* in dangerous waters, if the value can ever change.

Let's take the singleton part of this out of the equation, as it's not particularly relevant. Consider this simple example:

```
// Not safe!
public class BusyIndicator
{
    public bool IsBusy { get; set; }
}
```

Now if you have one thread which is along the lines of:

```
foo.IsBusy = true;
// do some work
foo.IsBusy = false;
```

and another thread, only started after `IsBusy` is set to true, that has:

```
// Do some work
while (foo.IsBusy) { }
```

... then it's possible that the second thread will spin *forever*... there's no memory barrier to ensure that it "sees" the change from the first thread.

You can implement this safely either using locking or using `Interlocked`, e.g.

```
// Safe (in terms of memory barriers)
public class BusyIndicator
{
    private int busy = 0;

    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref busy, 0, 0) == 1; }
        set { Interlocked.Exchange(ref busy, value ? 1 : 0); }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, that's what I was afraid of.  Glad I asked.

Comment: Is marking the variable with `volatile` helpful in this situation?

Comment: @gap: Maybe. To be honest, the *exact* details of `volatile` are very complex, and I try to avoid saying too much about them these days...

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined the property `IsBusy` as follows, then you can definitely have thread safety issues:

```
public bool IsBusy { get; set; }
```

The big issue here is the value can be checked and then changed before the value is set. That means you have a race condition. ONE way to solve this is:

```
// this is going to keep trying to lock until it succeeds, after which it 
//     will do whatever work needs done.
while (true) {
  bool lockObtained = false;
  lock (objectInstance) {
    if (!objectInstance.IsBusy) {
      lockObtained = true;
      objectInstance.IsBusy = true;
    }
  }

  if (lockObtained) {
    // good to go here

    // and don't forget to clear the IsBusy
    objectInstance.IsBusy = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

This uses the built in .NET locking mechanism to lock the object so you can check and set without worrying about process preemption in the middle.

Comment: First off, your property isn't reading your field.  Second, what would be the point of indicating whether or not you're busy if it's always false?

Comment: Well, without the initial value coming from a constructor this is pretty useless besides it is semantically a constant and you just want to avoid constant inlining by the compiler.

Comment: @Servy I agree. I was just showing an example of where they could technically be all right. I posted some code showing one possible implementation where locking is used to provide thread safety. Maybe I'll remove that initial example....

Comment: To your latest example, since there is no synchronization mechanisms provided it is *not* in fact safe.  The property value can actually be read before it is initialized, allowing an invalid value to be read.

Comment: @Servy Are you talking about the "side note" or the example? In the main example I use `lock(instance)` to provide thread safety. I'm happy to fix (or delete) the answer but I'm interested in where I made a mistake.

Comment: The latest example.  The one at the end, that you added last, without any synchronization mechanisms.

Comment: @Servy That begs the question - how do you read a member variable *before* you have an instance of the class?

Comment: @drew_w Well, technically it's not begging the question ([here's an exaplanation.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/22/begging-the-question.aspx))  And as to how you can do that, you can do all sorts of things in a multithreaded application.  C# only makes guarentees as to the observed ordering of operations within a single threaded app.  Almost none are made in a multithreaded app, and what there is  is virtually only around synchronization mechanisms.  This means the initialization of the data can be reordered to be after the constructor returning, to another thread.

Comment: @Servy Understood, but you can't access a (non-static) property without an instance of the class and you can't pass an instance to threads without instantiating it. Again, I can't fathom a situation where this would fail to be thread safe. That said, I'll take it out since it is besides the point for this answer.

Comment: `you can't pass an instance to threads without instantiating it`  That statement is true in a single threaded situation.  It is *not* true in a multithreaded situation.  You can assign an instance of an object to a variable *before its constructor has finished*, so long as the thread that is running the constructor never accesses the variable before the constructor finishes.  Another thread is certainly capable of doing this though.  That's what makes shared state in multithreaded code so scary.  The most basic of assumptions begin to break down without proper synchronization.

Comment: ok, now i can rest in peace

Comment: @Servy I appreciate the information & feedback! I suppose I still have a great deal to learn about threading...